# The name does not exist in the current context when using an if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I want to calculate Pi with the number of decimal places given by the user and when the input is 0 the variable piNumber should be set to '3' and not '3,' so that the output doesn't have a useless comma.

This works

```
        static string PiNumberFinder(int amountOfDigits)
    {
        string piNumber = "3,";
        int dividedBy = 11080585;
        int divisor = 78256779;
        int result;
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfDigits; i++)
        {
            if (dividedBy < divisor)
                dividedBy *= 10;

            result = dividedBy / divisor;

            string resultString = result.ToString();
            piNumber += resultString;

            dividedBy = dividedBy - divisor * result;
        }

        return piNumber;
    }
```

But with the if statement it doesn't

```
        static string PiNumberFinder(int amountOfDigits)
    {
        int dividedBy = 11080585;
        int divisor = 78256779;
        int result;
        if (amountOfDigits == 0)
        {
            string piNumber = "3";
        }
        else
        {
            string piNumber = "3,";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfDigits; i++)
        {
            if (dividedBy < divisor)
                dividedBy *= 10;

            result = dividedBy / divisor;

            string resultString = result.ToString();
            piNumber += resultString;  // I get an error here

            dividedBy = dividedBy - divisor * result;
        }

        return piNumber;  // I get an error here
    }
```

I get the error "The name 'piNumber' does not exist in the current context" twice for the lines pointed in the code above

Comment: You're defining the variable in the scope of the `if` statement. Move the variable outside of the `if` and assign it.

Comment: Declare string piNumber before if statment, and just change it inside of statement

Comment: Thanks, off-topic but in Python when the try statement raises no errors you can use the else statement. Is there something like this in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare and assign a value to `piNumber` variable inside `if` statement, therefore it isn't available outside this scope. Try to declare it before `if`

```cs
string piNumber;
if (amountOfDigits == 0)
{
    piNumber = "3";
}
else
{
    piNumber = "3,";
}
```

Comment: _piNumber.Trim(',');_